# How to record touch movements on Android keyboard?

Tags: android

I apologize if this is a stupid question. I have only taken an introductory Java class and am a beginner to Android.

I want to track the drawing made by a finger using Swype and record each stroke as an image or vector of some sort.

Is there a simple way to record a touch movement in another application, maybe by making an application running in the background?

Thank you and I appreciate any guidance!

Answer (score 0):

Touch events are consumed by the top-most view. Because swype doesn't have any kind of API you can hook into you won't be able to get that information. [Input Events | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html)

There might be some way to create a skeleton keyboard application that captures the gestures that people make over an image of the swype keyboard that then passes that gesture to the real swype, but I'd personally be worried about copyright unless it was just for personal use.